# Binary OR framebuffer blending

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader, framebuffer

I'm currently looking into an algorithm described within [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097849313000435) research paper, however I've come across a portion which I'm unclear of how it's been achieved.

> A grid is defined by placing a camera above the scene and adjusting its view frustum to enclose the area to be voxelized. This camera has an associated viewport with (w, h  ) dimensions. The scene is then rendered, constructing the voxelization in the frame buffer. A pixel (i,j) represents a column in the grid and each voxel within this column is binary encoded using the k  th bit of the RGBA value of the pixel. Therefore, the corresponding image represents a w×h×32 grid with one bit of information per voxel. This bit indicates whether a primitive passes through a cell or not. The union of voxels corresponding to the kth bit for all pixels defines a slice. Consequently, the image/texture encoding the grid is called a slicemap  . When a primitive is rasterized, a set of fragments are obtained. **A fragment shader is used in order to determine the position of the fragment in the column based on its depth. The result is then OR−ed with the current value of the frame buffer.**

Presumably one would achieve this by setting the [blend equation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlendEquation.xhtml) to use a binary-OR, however that's not an available option and I can't see a way to achieve it through manipulation of `glBlendFunc()`+`glBlendEquation()`

Additionally from my understanding it's not possible to read the framebuffer within the fragment shader. You can bind a texture to both the shader and framebuffer, however accessing this within the shader is [undefined behaviour](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Feedback_Loops) due to a lack of synchronisation.

The paper doesn't state whether OpenGL or Direct-X was used, however to the [best of my understanding](http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=9-4-10) it has the same `glBlendEquation()` limitations.

Am I missing something?

*I realise I could simply achieve the same result in 32 passes.*

Comment: The last sentence before the paragraph you quoted states "The voxelization method is an extension of the GPU method described in [26]". Have you read the ["Fast Scene Voxelization and Applications" paper by Eisemann](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3ebc/c2e5199aef395f0c63aadb93c16056e6b20a.pdf)? Another method would be the one described, for example, [here](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~pcozzi/OpenGLInsights/OpenGLInsights-SparseVoxelization.pdf) which uses image load/store operations.

Comment: Yeah I just thought to do that after posting the question, it mentions  'gl logic operations', this seems to be what I need. I posted answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL has a seperate [`glLogicOp()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glLogicOp.xhtml) for performing logical operations on the frame buffer.

This can be configured and enabled using

```
glLogicOp(GL_OR);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_LOGIC_OP);
```

Although the flag is `GL_COLOR_LOGIC_OP` the documentation implies this will also cover alpha values.

*It's slightly better described in citation [26](https://hal.inria.fr/file/index/docid/510221/filename/voxels05-final.pdf)*

Comment: Alternatively, you could read [this page](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Logical_Operation).